# Show that if A, B, and C are sets, then |A∪B ∪C| = |A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B ∩C|+|A∩B ∩C|.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm needing some help with this problem. I know you must show that $$|A ∪ B ∪ C| \subseteq |A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B ∩C|+|A∩B ∩C|$$ and that $$|A|+|B|+|C|−|A∩B|−|A∩C|−|B ∩C|+|A∩B ∩C| \subseteq |A ∪ B ∪ C|$$ and I got to $$A + B + C \cap (\bar{A} \cup \bar{B} \cup \bar{C}) + A \cap B \cap C$$ but am getting stuck there. Am I going the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Note: measures of set cardinality are not themselves sets.  $\lvert X\rvert \subseteq \lvert Y\rvert$ is not sensible.  Do you mean $\lvert X\rvert \leq \lvert Y\rvert$ ?

Comment: Have you tried proving the simpler $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$?

Comment: The last line similarly confuses sets with their sizes.  Perhaps union is meant in places where you wrote addition?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: draw a picture, and get pens of some different and easily seen colors. Make the venn diagram corresponding to these pictures. In order to count the size of this set, we will count in pieces. First, we count $A$, so let's shade it the first color. Then, we count $B$, so we shade it another color. What do we have to do with the sections of the diagram that have been colored twice? What happens with the piece in the center?

Comment: It basically comes out to everything being colored once, but with the intersecting pieces of A, B, and C not colored, but the center piece colored because of the last A+B+C. Is this correct?

Comment: Well if you color A and B, then their intersection has been colored twice. You've overcounted that intersection. So then we need to subtract off the stuff that's been double counted. But the center piece will have been added three times, once for each set, and then removed three times, once for each intersection, so now it has to be counted again!

Comment: @ChaseMcDermott So to avoid over counting the size of the triple union, you *include* the size of each set, *exclude* the size of the intersects of each pair, and then *include* the size of intersection all three again.  Hmm... This *principle of inclusion and exclusion* seems rather a useful thing to remember.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. @GrahamKemp. How is the principle of inclusion and exclusion applied when the A in A+B is more than one variable?

Comment: Basically i have it and understand it as a Venn diagram now, but I am not sure how to prove it directly. @AlfredYerger

Answer (score 1):

You didn't need to show anything is a subset of anything else (and certainly not things which are not sets).

$\bbox[white]{\begin{align}\lvert X\cup Y\rvert ~=~& \Big\lvert \big(X\cap Y^\complement \big)\cup\big(X\cap Y \big)\cup\big( X^\complement\cap Y\big)\Big\rvert \\ ~=~& \color{white}{\big\lvert X\cap Y^\complement\big\rvert+\big\lvert X\cap Y\big\rvert+\big\lvert X^\complement\cap Y\big\rvert} \\ ~=~& \big\lvert X\cap Y^\complement\big\rvert+2\big\lvert X\cap Y\big\rvert+\big\lvert X^\complement\cap Y\big\rvert-\big\lvert X\cap Y\big\rvert
\\ ~=~& \color{white}{\Big\lvert\big( X\cap Y^\complement\big)\cup\big( X\cap Y\big)\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\big(X\cap Y\big)\cup\big( X^\complement\cap Y\big)\Big\rvert-\big\lvert X\cap Y\big\rvert}
\\ ~=~& \lvert X\rvert+\big\lvert Y\big\rvert-\big\lvert X\cup Y\big\rvert
\\[2ex]\big\lvert A \cup(B\cup C)\big\rvert~=~& \lvert A\rvert+\big\lvert B\cup C\big\rvert-\big\lvert A\cap (B\cup C)\big\rvert
\\ ~=~& \lvert A\rvert+\bigl(\lvert B\rvert+\lvert C \rvert-\lvert B\cup C\rvert\bigr)-\big\lvert (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\big\rvert
\\ \vdots~~~&
\end{align}}$